# How to find the difference between two arrays after calling a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to subtract the earliest date from two arrays:

```
def days_pending
  start = [object.created_at]
  finish = [Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
  if object.app_sign_date
    start.push(object.app_sign_date)
  end
  if object.submitted_date
    start.push(object.submitted_date)
  end
  if object.inforce_date
    finish.push(object.inforce_date)
  end
  if object.closed_date
    finish.push(object.closed_date)
  end
  finish.min - start.min
```

I have no problem calling `min` on the arrays, but have a problem calling the `min` method and then subtracting. I get `NoMethodError: undefined  method`-' for "2015-01-01":String`.

Comment: You are subtracting strings, not dates. You can't subtract strings. `Time.now - Date.today.to_time` works perfectly fine. If you want to subtract dates/times, subtract `Date`s/`Time`s, don't use `strftime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the array `finish` has first element as string not the date. you need to add appropriate object instead ie. date or datetime

```
finish = [Time.now]
```

or

```
finish = [DateTime.now]
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, what you got is a string.
Change to `Time.now` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output to be in the form "2015-01-01" you could use parse:

```
Time.parse(finish.min) - start.min
```